# Electrical Noise in Raspberry Pi with Multiple USB Connection

Tags: usb, noise, raspberry-pi

I'm currently in the process of creating a mobile robot using a Raspberry Pi. The robot incorporates three devices (ODrive, RPLidar, and UWB), all connected to the Raspberry Pi through USB ports. When only one or two devices are connected, there are no issues with disconnection or errors. However, when all three devices are connected simultaneously, I experience disconnections and delays in response.

I've rigorously tested the code and executed the robot three times (3x) to ensure its functionality, and it performed well on each occasion. Interestingly, upon retesting without any modifications, issues such as "has no attribute 'something'" began to emerge.

I suspect that there might be electrical noise present. The challenge lies in not knowing how to measure the noise in this setup and identify the specific type of filter or devices needed. Additionally, investing solely in high-quality USB filters, hubs, or other devices is not justifiable without a clear understanding of why such a purchase is crucial. I cant progress again because of this challenge.

[image]

Comment: How can you be sure it's not just collisions on the BUS? That would explain delays and worst case data loss.

Comment: I always put RPlidar, UWB and ODrive in sequence. RPLidar and UWB connects to ttyUSB. If lidar is connected first, it will be connected to the lowest ttyUSB* then UWB connects to the largest while ODrive only connects to ttyACM*. That's the logic I have observed when I typed <ls /dev/tty*> in RPI Terminal

Comment: Do the problems occur when the odrive is activating the motors?

Comment: Yes. The problem of disconnection occasionally happens with Odrive. It is okay when doing calibration at the startup however, when is supposedly moving based on the logic condition, the error occurs.

Notably, this same code and odrive already works, and I have video but just cant replicate again due to that error.

Comment: Are the devices powered by RPi's USB ports? Can it really output enough current for this on USB ports?

Comment: Why do you expect a hobbyist toy board to fulfill any form of immunity or emissions requirements? You get what you pay for.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if it powers enough but I see it works for a couple of time. Additionally, as for now, I am running in a wired mode, not battery mode. So my RPI is powered by 5V power supply. Lidar and UWB is powered by RPI through USB ports. Odrive is being powered by 24V PSU but there is USB cable which is connected to RPI port for enabling its functionality.

Comment: Originally, the inspiration of this project uses Nvidia Jetson Nano but just go for meantime for RPI for proof of concept. I just have no actual idea of what will be the advantage of that board compared to RPI since mostly of some videos in YT also uses RPI.

Comment: There is no info to work on. We don't even know which Raspberry Pi model you have, and how much it can provide current out, and how much your USB devices plugged into it need to work correctly. Or if they even use USB for power, and if not, how are they powered and from where.

Comment: _"I suspect that there might be electrical noise present."_ No need. Measure and find out!

Comment: Is it possible the usb power becomes overloaded when all three are comnected? Check with a meter. Also when using usb based serial devices on Linux I URGE you to check out the aliases in /dev/serial - you an open devices by serial number or actual usb position.

Comment: And to add to your diagnostic tool kit, check out lsusb (-t or -v flags) and dmesg, lsusb -t gives you devices and connection speeds really easily - 480Mbps devices need good usb2 cables. Dmesg will let you know if you have any disconnects or other errors - but you’ll REALLY have to search in there.